# Load Image (Not Bitmap Thumbnail) From Android Camera Intent

Tags: android, image, firebase, android-camera, firebase-storage

I am using the camera intent to allow users to take pictures and upload images to Firebase storage. I am noticing that during this process, considerable image quality is being lost since I am pulling the bitmap and not the actual image file. I would obviously like to limit file size and compress where necessary, however I would like to retain original image quality as well. Here is where I call the camera intent and prompt the user to take a photo:

```
 case 1:
          Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
          if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getApplication().getPackageManager()) != null) {
          startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, TAKE_PICTURE);
         } else {Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.camera_error), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
         break;
```

Here is the .onActivityResult() method where I retrieve the image data:

```
  case TAKE_PICTURE:
            //TODO: Limit file size to prevent reaching Firebase storage limit
            if (resultCode == CreateActivity.RESULT_OK) {
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                mImagePreview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                mImagePreview.buildDrawingCache();
                mImagePreview.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
                encodeBitmapAndSaveToFirebase(imageBitmap);
            }
            break;
```

And save to Firebase:

```
private void encodeBitmapAndSaveToFirebase(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();

    String uniqueID = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    mFileRef = mStorageRef.child(uniqueID);
    UploadTask uploadTask = mFileRef.putBytes(data);
    uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error Loading Photo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            // taskSnapshot.getMetadata() contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
            Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
            resultImageURL = downloadUrl.toString();
            Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                    .load(resultImageURL)
                    .into(mImagePreview);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: you are not getting full image , you are just geting thubnail it just retunt thubnail of image wich you capture thats for u facing problem
Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

Comment: try another way to get image

Comment: How do I get the full image? What extra do I use?

Answer (score 2):

Here, quality => The quality we want our picture to have on a scale of 1 – 100.
targetWidth & targetHeight => This gives you the image size in px.

```
takePicture(){
  Camera.getPicture({
   quality : 95,
   destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
   sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
   allowEdit : true,
   encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.PNG,
   targetWidth: 500,
   targetHeight: 500,
   saveToPhotoAlbum: true
 }).then(imageData => {
   this.guestPicture = imageData;
 }, error => {
   console.log("ERROR -> " + JSON.stringify(error));
  });
}
```

Comment: So this doesn't use the camera intent? I feel the camera intent is easiest as it prompts the user to say "OK" or "Cancel" during the process....

Comment: Does the intent only return a bitmap?

Comment: This code looks like JavaScript.  The question is about Android, and the sample code given was Java.

Answer (score 1):

The Google tutorial for taking a picture in Android using an external camera app is this: https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

If you follow that example, you will have created a file where the camera app will save the image data.  If you don't want to lose any quality in the image, upload the contents of that file directly.  As it stands now, you are uploading the thumbnail of the image, which is going to be nowhere near the size and quality of the source image.